# Best practice when using multiple items in a section with IGListKit

Tags: iglistkit

I'm struggling with how IGListKit handles multiple items in a section. Are those items individually "diffable" for updates, or is it only the object that contains them that gets updated, and subsequently updates the entire section?

I'm trying to display a list of "events". Events are grouped by day. So if there are 7 events that fall over 3 days you might have:

DAY 1
•event 1
•event 2

DAY 2
•event 3
•event 4
•event 5
•event 6

DAY 3
•event 7

What is the proper way to set this up? I could make an "EventsHolder" object that was "IGListDiffable", yes. But I'd rather the "IGListDiffable" portion be each event. So if event 2 changed it doesn't reload all of the first EventHolder.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out `IGListBindingSectionController` on the master branch of IGListKit, it does exactly what you're describing:

- Take a "top level" object and a section controller
- Convert that object into an array of diffable view models
- Create and configure cells based on those view models

There's a PR with examples here:

https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/pull/494